# C#: will there be a recursion limit issue with this approach borrowed from javascript

Tags: c#

Wondering if an approach that's possible in javascript is OK to use in C#.

In a javascript application, when a large number of web requests have to be made one after the other, the UI can be kept responsive by eschewing a for-loop, and instead, using a stack (an array) and events. The next URL is popped from the array in the success eventhandler, which keeps making another request until the stack is empty. Can a similar approach be taken in C# with a Stack? Is the following legit?

```
     urlStack .... // stack of urls
     myRequestMaker = new WebRequestMaker();   // my custom object
     myRequestMaker.ResponseReceived += (s,e) =>
     {
         // e contains info whether the request succeeded, failed, or timed out

         url = pop another url from urlStack if it's not empty
        (s as WebRequestMaker).MakeWebRequest(url);
     }

    url = pop first url from urlStack
    myRequestMaker.MakeWebRequest(url);
```

(The *ReponseReceived* event is raised by the WebRequestMaker object also when the request times out, BTW)

In javascript, you can hit maximum recursion limits using this approach, and to get around that you can wrap the method invocation, made inside the success eventhandler, in a SetTimeout. Will invokving myRequestMaker's *MakeWebRequest* method inside the ResponseReceived eventhandler run into analogous issues?

Comment: You could do that in C# but you would be better off using the new `await` feature of C# 5 to do task-based asynchrony, rather than rolling your own as is done here.

Comment: @Eric Lippert. Thank you. I see that 5.0 requires VS2012 but I am still at 2010, for a while longer.

Comment: You can do task-based asynchrony in C# 4, but you can't use the `await` keyword which makes it somewhat easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your code will eventually hit `StackOverflowException`. You can simulate `setTimeout` behaviour using the `System.Task` class that runs code asynchronously:

```
myRequestMaker.ResponseReceived += (s,e) =>
 {
     // e contains info whether the request succeeded, failed, or timed out

     url = pop another url from urlStack if it's not empty
     Task.Run(() => (s as WebRequestMaker).MakeWebRequest(url));
 }
```

(of course, your urlStack now should be a concurrent to avoid racing conditions)

Optimally, you would not use the code above, but implement a `MakeWebRequestAsync` method that gets your job done asynchronously. Most built-in long-running/blockin methods (such as reading and writing from/to streams) in .Net already implement such a method, so if your `WebRequestMaker` is actually using a `System.Net.WebClient` you can call the async version. More information about tasks and async/await can be found in MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and suggestions.  If I have to make 10,000 requests (to determine which links in our database are dead links) would I simply iterate the url list and invoke theMakeWebRequestAsync method with each iteration?

Comment: It seems I've misunderstood your question. The answer above is valid if you wish to read the requests one after another. If you'd like to iterate and make all the request simultaneously a better approach would be to use Parallel.For/Foreach. Here's a example implementation - http://pastebin.com/J3BVETB1 (I've added the one-after-another solution as well)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will, every function call pushed to the call stack and poped when it finishes.
The error you mention is fired when the call stack is full, not in javascript, in most languages (in fact I don't know any that doesn't).

You should apply the same logic as you do in Javascript here.